# How to run macro via sheets API?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, google-sheets-macros

I know you can record a macro in google sheets. Curious how I would make the call to V4 sheets API?

I didn't see anything related to run macro https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/

Comment: Google Sheets Macros is managed by a function of the container-bound script of the Spreadsheet. So when you want to run the function from outside, unfortunately, it cannot be achieved by Sheets API. You can achieve it by [the scripts.run method of Apps Script API](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/reference/rest/v1/scripts/run) and [Web Apps](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web).

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comment by @tanaike, this **cannot** be done using Sheets API.

But as macros are bounded to a Google Apps Script function you can run a macro by running the bounded function with the Google Apps Script API.

You can find [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/how-tos/execute) the documentation from Google Apps Script API run method.